# Best way to gather musical data

Tags: data-mining, dataset, scraping

I am looking for a relatively large amount of jazz (and other) solos to use for data science purposes - probably somewhere up to a 100 transctipts. Although that is not that much and many pdf transcripts are available, I want the data to be in a format where I can easily access all the information in Python (which note was played and at what beat). Manually writing all that data would, however, be very tedious and time-consuming.

Thus my question: does anyone know of any software that automatically reads pdf transcripts and puts it in a different file format, or alternatively of a website with transcripts already in a format in which I can access all the data easily from Python?

Comment: Any chance you can get the music as Midi files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for musical optical character recognition software. A google search pointed me to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_OCR) where links to two open source applications resides: [Audiveris](https://audiveris.kenai.com/) and [OpenOMR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openomr/). I can not vouch for either program.